# MTurk Command Line Tools Error: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services, java, mechanicalturk

I am using the Mechanical Turk command line tools on Windows. When I try to run a command (e.g., getBalance, createQualificationType), I always get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Any clues as to what I could look at to fix this would be greatly appreciated!!

I have tried  updating my key and secret key to no avail.

Note: I can get help for the commands by using -help, but I cannot run the commands themselves.

This error occurs whether I am running either JRE 1.5.0_06-b05, 1.5.0_22-b03, or 1.7.0_17-b02. The command line tools documentation states, ["You must have the Java JRE 1.5.X (JRE 5). The Command Line Tools are not 100% compatible with JRE 6."](http://web.mit.edu/cathywu/Public/AMT/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.0/UserGuide.html)

Since I am using the version of the command line tools packaged with JRE, I have also uninstalled my JRE. I get the same error.

Comment: I have found the answer. The JRE packed with the Mechanical Turk Command Line Tools does not work for the CLTs. It should be deleted, a new version of JRE should be installed, and then the JAVA_HOME system-level variable should be updated to the correct path for the newly installed JRE.

After this, the mturk.properties file may need to updated to connect over https. 

Detailed instructions for doing this can be found in [this thread on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=388586), posted by user uwviscoglab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnsupportedClassVersionError` means that you are trying to use a Java class that was compiled with a newer JDK on an older Java runtime environment. For example, you have a class that was compiled with JDK 7, and you are trying to use it on a Java 6 or older runtime environment.

Java is downwards compatible; newer Java runtime environments can run Java classes compiled with older versions without modifications, but not the other way around.

Check with what version the class you are trying to use was compiled, and use a Java runtime environment with the same version or newer to run the class.

You can check your Java runtime environment and JDK versions with:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Comment: Thanks! The first command states that I am using JRE version 1.7.0_17-b02. The documentation for the MTurk command line tools state that it requires using version 1.5 and that it is not compatible with version 1.6 (no mention of 1.7, so I assume the documentation predates it). http://web.mit.edu/cathywu/Public/AMT/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.0/UserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the CLT installer installs a JRE that is too old to run the tools included in the installer.  Seems like a serious bug (certainly annoying).

You can fix by installing and using a more recent JDK.

This post contains instructions on how to do so:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=388586#388585